# How can i reduce the CPU usage of Google's Inbox

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

Even with all my extensions disabled Google Inbox takes 2-5% constantly and 20-40% in spikes every so often. This is also without the tab having focus.

Currently I just open Inbox when i need it and close the tab, but that's annoying. None of my other tabs do this.

I've done the basics like restarting the web browser and clearing web data.

I'd like to always have Google Inbox open without it draining my battery by using massive CPU resources.